# Getting turtles to spend energy while moving on a least cost path in a network environment

Tags: netlogo

I’m creating a model in which turtles choose and traverse a least cost path in a network environment, one node at a time.

I’m using the nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to primitive from the NW extension to let my turtles choose a path. Relevant snippets of my code (which so far works fine) are below:

```
undirected-link-breed [ routes route ]
undirected-link-breed [ tracts tract ]

breed [ stalkers stalker ]

stalkers-own [ energy ]

links-own [ difficulty ]

to setup-network
  ask routes [
    set thickness 2
    set color white
    set difficulty 1
  ]
  ask tracts [
    set thickness 2
    set color black
    set difficulty 2
  ]
end

to enter-the-zone
  ask stalkers [
    let path nobody
    let target one-of nodes-on patch -10 42
    ask nodes-on patch-here [ set path but-first nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to one-of nodes-on patch -10 42  difficulty ]
    ifelse  patch-here != ( patch -10 42 )
      [
    face first path
    move-to first path
    ]
    [ return_to_base
    ]
  ]
  tick
end

to return_to_base
  move-to patch -258 -231
end
```

However, I would like to add an “energy” attribute to my turtles that depletes a little every time they reach a new node. The catch is: I would like this loss of energy to be equal to the difficulty of the link between the node they are now and the node in which they just were.

What would be the best way to implement that?

Thanks in advance for the help.